# How to exclude properties from JsonConvert.PopulateObject that don't exist in some base type or interface?

Tags: c#, serialization, interface, json.net, populate

Is it possible to define options to JsonConvert.PopulateObject to exclude fields given in a json, that does not exists in the target object's interface implementation?

```
public interface IElementWriter
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public interface IElementUpdateWriter : IElementWriter
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
}
public interface IElementInsertWriter : IElementWriter
{
    DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Element:IElementWriter, IElementInsertWriter, IElementUpdateWriter {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IElementWriter element = new Element() { ID = 1, Name = "SourceName", CreationDate=DateTime.Today, FirstName="SourceFirstName" };

    string json = "{ id:'8', Name:'newName', FirstName:'newFirstName' }";

    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, element, new JsonSerializerSettings() {

    });
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Result**:

> {"ID":8,"Name":"newName","CreationDate":"2019-06-05T00:00:00+02:00","FirstName":"newFirstName"}

**Required** because IElementWriter does not have ID nor FirstName:

> {"ID":1,"Name":"newName","CreationDate":"2019-06-05T00:00:00+02:00","FirstName":"SourceFirstName"}

Comment: There isn't any setting that does that, you would need to add attributes to your `Element` type (which you probably don't want to do) or use a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples).  Want an example of the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple setting in `JsonSerializerSettings` that will cause [`JsonConvert.PopulateObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject.htm) to populate an instance of a derived type as if it were an instance of some base type.  To confirm this, you can check the source for [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.Populate()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L66), which takes as arguments only a `reader` and `target` and pulls the target's [contract](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract.htm) directly from its type:

```
public void Populate(JsonReader reader, object target)
{
    Type objectType = target.GetType();

    JsonContract contract = Serializer._contractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
```

Thus your options include:

1. Modify the definition of your `Element` class and add `[JsonIgnore]` to the properties you don't want to populate.

   You probably don't want to do this because it will prevent the properties from ever being serialized or deserialized.
2. Use a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) to ignore all properties of `Element` that are not also properties of `IElementWriter`.

   This would seem to be the better solution.

Assuming you choose option #2, you can introduce the following custom contract resolver:

```
public class UpcastingContractResolver<TDerived, TBase> : DefaultContractResolver where TDerived: TBase
{
    readonly HashSet<string> baseProperties = ((JsonObjectContract)JsonSerializer.Create().ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(TBase)))
        .Properties.Select(p => p.UnderlyingName)
        .ToHashSet();

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        if (type == typeof(TDerived) || type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(TDerived)))
        {
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (!baseProperties.Contains(property.UnderlyingName))
                    property.Ignored = true;
            }
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Then, cache an instance somewhere for performance as [suggested by Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver):

```
static IContractResolver elementAsElementWriterResolver = new UpcastingContractResolver<Element, IElementWriter>();
```

And populate your `element` as follows:

```
// Only populate those properties present in IElementWriter
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, element, new JsonSerializerSettings
                           { 
                               ContractResolver = elementAsElementWriterResolver 
                           });
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jEuAfX).

Comment: Thanks for that. I take it "as it".